# Count rows with equivalent value in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to find the count of rows where the entered answer is the same as the correct answer. Here's an example:

```
WorkerID      Answer      Correct
1             A           A
1             B           C
2             A           D
```

I would then get the following result:

```
WorkerID    AnswerCount # Correct
1           2           1
2           1           0
```

So far I have (conceptually):

```
SELECT worker_id, count(*), count(Answer == Correct) FROM answer_table GROUP BY WorkerID
```

What would be the correct query here?

Comment: You can combine conditions in your WHERE, such as `WHERE (Answer = Correct) AND (your other criteria....)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `count()`, you want `sum()`:

```
SELECT worker_id, count(*) as AnswerCount, sum(Answer = Correct) as NumCorrect
FROM answer_table
GROUP BY WorkerID;
```

`count()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values that the expression takes on.  You want to count the number of matches, which is the number of trues.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want :

```
select count(*)
from yourTable
where answer = correct
group by workerId
```

Basically, what you need to do is

- Select all where answer = correct.
- group them by workerId.
- count the num of rows (where answer = correct) for each group.

**Edit :** To answer to your edited question,

```
select count(*), count(b.workerId)
from yourTable
left join (select * 
           from yourTable 
           where answer = correct) b using(workerId)
group by workerId
```

Comment: Please see updated question, as I cannot use a WHERE clause in the statement, it needs to be part of the select.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
select workerid,count(*) as numberOfAnswers,
sum(case
           when answer=correct then 1
           else 0 end) as correctAnswers
from tbl
group by workerid
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0835/5)